# Facebook User Access Token not returning all user info

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

After initiating the Facebook login process, i call `loginResult.getAccessToken().getToken()` to retrieve the user's access token for the current session.

I want to use the returned access token in a Graph API call to retrieve the user's information such as public profile to help in oauth authentication flow.

The problem is that when I test the returned access token with Graph API, all i get is the user's name and user's id. But if i test using the Graph API Explorer, the access token it returns gives much more information than just the name and id.

Is there any extra permission I need to ask of the Facebook login so as to get an access token that returns more data?

Comment: What all permission you are asking while generating the token??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify the fields you want to get, it´s called "Declarative Fields": `/me?fields=name,email,...`

If you don´t specify the fields, you will only get `id` and `name`. And of course you need to make sure to authorize with the correct permissions.